# MySQL Query Two Tables with different column lookup

Tags: mysql

How to make this syntax works :

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  uploads,
  audienceuploadassociation 
WHERE 
  uploads.member_id = '1'
  AND uploads.member_school_id='1' 
  AND subject = 'Maths' 
  AND uploads.upload_id = audienceuploadassociation.upload_id 
  AND topic = 'Integers' 
  AND year IN(7, 8, 9) 
  AND audienceuploadassociation.audiencename LIKE (Parents, Teachers, Community)
```

Comment: Can you tell us what problem are you facing, what is the table structure, what is the data in the table and what is the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `LIKE` clause is faulty.  I suspect that you intend to use [an `IN()` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) instead:

```
AND audienceuploadassociation.audiencename IN ('Parents', 'Teachers', 'Community')
```

If you are trying to match partial strings with `LIKE`, you need to `OR` them together in a `()` group, as in:

```
AND (
  audienceuploadassociation.audiencename LIKE 'Parents%'
  OR audienceuploadassociation.audiencename LIKE 'Teachers%'
  OR audienceuploadassociation.audiencename LIKE 'Community%'
)
```

Note also, that the implicit join syntax you are using (comma-separated tables) is deprecated in favor of an explicit `JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  uploads.*,
  audienceuploadassociation.*
FROM
  /* Explicit JOIN  with ON clause */
  uploads
  JOIN audienceuploadassociation ON uploads.upload_id = audienceuploadassociation.upload_id 
WHERE 
  uploads.member_id = '1'
  AND uploads.member_school_id='1' 
  AND subject = 'Maths' 
  AND topic = 'Integers' 
  AND year IN(7, 8, 9) 
  AND audienceuploadassociation.audiencename IN ('Parents', 'Teachers', 'Community')
```

Finally, I would recommend explicitly naming the columns you want rather than doing `SELECT *`, so you get them in a deterministic order, and guard against the addition of other columns later that you don't need in this query:

```
SELECT 
  uploads.upload_id,
  uploads.other_column,
  uploads.topic,
  audienceuploadassociation.audiencename,
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Let me try with that, will get back with the outcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  uploads,
  audienceuploadassociation 
WHERE 
  uploads.member_id = '1'
  AND uploads.member_school_id='1' 
  AND subject = 'Maths' 
  AND uploads.upload_id = audienceuploadassociation.upload_id 
  AND topic = 'Integers' 
  AND year IN(7, 8, 9) 
  AND audienceuploadassociation.audiencename IN ('Parents', 'Teachers', 'Community');
```